# MySQL two tables two columns COUNT

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

> TEAMS - team_id and team_name (among other stuff)
>   SCHEDULE - game_id, team_a, team_b, team_a_id, team_a_id (among other stuff)

I am trying to create a result where I find out the number of times `team_name` (or `team_id`) shows up in either column `team_a` or `team_b` (or `team_a_id` or `team_b_id`)

TEAMS
team_id   team_name
1001      New York
1011      Cleveland
1021      Detroit
1031      Houston

SCHEDULE
game_id   team_a     team_b    team_a_id    team_b_id
1         New York   Cleveland  1001        1011
2         New York    Detroit   1001        1021
3         Cleveland   Houston   1011        1031

answer:
New York 2
Cleveland 2
Detroit 1
Houston 1

Comment: can you give sample records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select count(*)
from teams t
join schedule s on (s.team_a = t.team_name OR s.team_b = t.team_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way

```
Select t.team_name,Sum(allteams.teamcount) as NumberOfTimes
From teams t
inner join(
select team_a_id as team_ID, 1 as teamcount From Schedule
Union 
Select team_b_id, 1 From Schedule
) allteams
on allteams.Team_ID = t.Team_ID
Group By t.team_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM teams
WHERE $teamID IN (team_a, team_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty simple unless I'm missing something.  Just select a count, and use a [WHERE OR clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp).

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM schedule
WHERE team_a = 'Team Name'
OR team_b = 'Team Name'
```

Alternatively:

```
WHERE team_a_id = 'Team ID'
OR team_b_id = 'Team ID'
```